# Finding a Basis of a Polynomial Space using Eigenvectors from a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, linear-transformations

I'm working on a homework assignment and think I've got the answer, but wanted to double check that I'm interpreting it correctly. The problem and subproblems are as follows:

> Let $T: P_2({\rm I\!R}) \to P_2({\rm I\!R})$ be a linear map defined by $$T(f(x)) = f(x)+(x+1)f'(x)$$ and let $\beta = \{1,x,x^2\}$ be a basis for $P_2({\rm I\!R})$
>
> 1. Determine the eigenvalues of $[T]_\beta$<br
> 2. For each eigenvalue of $[T]_\beta$, find the corresponding eigenvectors<br
> 3. If possible, find a basis for $P_2({\rm I\!R})$ consiting of eigenvectors

---

So I found the answers for 1 and 2, which was fairly straightforward once I created the transformation matrix of $T$ with respect to basis $\beta$, but 3 is giving me some issues. Given that $\beta$ is already the standard basis vectors for $P_2({\rm I\!R})$, couldn't I just use the eigenvectors found in SubProblem 2 to create said basis eigenvectors? If so, would it be as simple as just multiplying the basis $\beta$ by each eigenvector to attain the new eigenvector basis representation?

Comment: Your work seems fine to me. All you have to do is to try to creat a basis for your vector space only consisting by eigenvectors. Hint: look at each proper subspace associated at each eigenvalue

Comment: If nothing comes from here, come back later and we will help you

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 1):

A basis of eigenvectors is $\{1,x+1,2x^2+4x+3\}$, which correspond to the eigenvalues $1$, $2$, and $3$ respectively. So, take $\alpha=\{1,x+1,2x^2+4x+3\}$, and $\alpha$ is a basis of $P_2(\Bbb R)$ which consists of eigenvectors.